# My sql HAVING clause doesnt seems to run when my `WHERE CASE WHEN` evaluates to false

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a statement where it works if I remove my `CASE WHEN 1 != 1` condition. I get microposts back that have `m.content = '<p>hi</p>'` and tags that have `ARRAY['hello', 'gday']` in them.

My knowledge is that my `HAVING` clause should still run and return microposts with matching tags when the `WHERE CASE WHEN` condition evaluates to `false` IE it doesnt filter by `m.content = '<p>hi</p>'`, and return microposts that have `ARRAY['hello', 'gday']` tags associated with them.

But this is not the case, when my `WHERE` condition doesn't run because the `CASE` condition evaluates to `false` it seems `HAVING` also doesn't run, and I get returned 0 results. Is this expected behavior and if so why??

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM microposts AS m 
JOIN taggings tt ON m.id = tt.taggable_id 
JOIN tags t ON t.id = tt.tag_id 
WHERE CASE WHEN 1 != 1 THEN m.content = '<p>hi</p>' END\
GROUP BY m.id 
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(t.name ORDER BY t.name)::text[] @> ARRAY['hello', 'gday']
```

**EDIT** Actual code with ruby string interpolation

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM microposts AS m 
JOIN taggings tt ON m.id = tt.taggable_id 
JOIN tags t ON t.id = tt.tag_id 
WHERE CASE WHEN #{my_string} != '' THEN m.content = #{my_string} END
GROUP BY m.id 
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(t.name ORDER BY t.name)::text[] @> ARRAY['hello', 'gday']
```

Comment: It is not what we do not know that gets into trouble, but what we  do know that is not so. In this case your statement "my knowledge ... false" is itself incorrect. The HAVING clause processed after the WHERE clause, and only processes what remains once the where completes. See [Order of SQL operations](https://www.eversql.com/sql-order-of-operations-sql-query-order-of-execution/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use `case`, then the logic would be:

```
WHERE CASE WHEN 1 != 1 THEN m.content = '<p>hi</p>' ELSE true END
```

That is, you need to explicitly return `true`.  Otherwise the `CASE` expressions returns `NULL`, which is treated as "false" in a `WHERE` clause.

However, I don't recommend a `CASE` expression for this.  Instad:

```
WHERE (1 <> 1 AND m.content = '<p>hi</p>') OR
      (1 = 1)
```

Of course, this can be simplified, but I assume that the `1 <> 1` is due to parameter substitution.

Comment: Sorry I added the actual code with ruby string interpolation to show my logic. So your saying my `HAVING` clause does not run because `false` returns the entire statement?

Comment: Ok you are right adding in `ELSE true` seems to correct this..

Answer (score 0):

`Where` clause simply goes with :

```
where (1 != 1 and m.content = '<p>hi</p>')
```

However, first condition would never return true (`1 != 1`). So, you can simplify with this :

```
where (m.content = '<p>hi</p>')
```

Comment: Actually `1 != 1` will never return **true**, so the first condition is equivalent to `where false`

Comment: Yeah but I use string interpolation and my string varies. The actual code would be `'' != ''` when the input string is empty. Then I do not want my `WHERE` clause to run. So my question still stands. I was just use `1 != 1` as a example...